# float 0 returns as empty string in php

Tags: php

could anyone explain why float 0 is empty? The code below will show "weird"

```
$empty = (float)"0";
if($empty == "")
  echo "weird";
```

On the other hand if i were to the code below, it will never show "weird".

```
$empty = (float)"0.01";
if($empty == "")
  echo "weird";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in PHP the following expressions are true:

```
0 == ""
0.0 == ""
```

*not* because `$empty` here is the empty string `""`.

You can perform a *typed* equality check using `===`, and these expressions will appear false, as expected:

```
0 === ""
0.0 === ""
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not weird at all, that's expected. Remember, in PHP `0` evaluates to FALSE, as does an empty string. To avoid this, use `===` which tests for strict equality ( a === b means, "does a == b and am I comparing apples to apples", while a == b means "do these things have the same value?" (it doesn't matter if I am comparing apples and goats))

Try this:

```
$empty = (float)"0";
if($empty === "")
  echo "weird";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how loose comparison works in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php